# INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Necesito saber qué podría estar mal en esta query:

```
INSERT INTO `turnos_enviados`(`rut`,`hora_envio`, `turnos`)
SELECT "12345678", `hora_envio`+1, "string cualquiera"
FROM `turnos_enviados` ORDER BY `hora_envio` ASC LIMIT 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `rut`="12345678", `hora_envio`=(SELECT `hora_envio`+1 FROM `turnos_enviados` ORDER BY `hora_envio` ASC LIMIT 1), `turnos`="string cualquiera";
```

Pues me arroja estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que funciona todo perfecto, sin errores cuando ejecuto la query, incluso el `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` está bueno.

Tal vez sea error del PHPMyAdmin, pero de no ser así, tal vez yo esté haciendo algo mal que en algún momento pueda fallar, solo eso me incomoda aunque funcione perfecto.

Realmente está todo bien?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En efecto, parece que había un defecto en una versión pasada de phpMyAdmin que causaba esto con la expresión `ON DUPLICATE KEY` específicamente: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11628.

Puedes tratar de actualizar el phpMyAdmin que usas. En cualquier caso, no te preocupes, que tu consulta va a funcionar bien sin importar lo que phpMyAdmin diga. Es un problema cosmético no mas.

Comment: gracias, uso XAMPP 3.2.2, estará muy viejito ya? creo haberlo descargado hace no más de 6 meses.

Comment: No, ahora que estoy mirando mas de cerca, parece que la corrección a este problema es relativamente reciente, y aun no está disponible. Parece que el fix viene en la versión 4.6.5 de phpMyAdmin, pero la última versión oficial solo es 4.6.4 por ahora. Habrá que ser paciente.

Comment: se agradece la info, me quedo tranquilo.